# What application inserts html comment tags around PHP tags in SQL query?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm using PDO and prepared statements to insert entries into a MySQL database.  Works great so far.  I realize that my question is basically rendered moot if the input is also sanitized with a function like `htmlentities()`, but as a matter of curiosity, does php code that's been injected into a database ever get executed on the way back out?

For example:

```
    $connection = new PDO(//some database info);
    $query = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO House (Rooms) VALUES (:newroom);");
    $query->bindValue(':newroom', $_POST['newroom'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->execute();
```

Now let's say a user enters the value for $_POST['newroom'] as:

```
    <?php var_dump($connection); ?>
```

This goes into the database as-is, because although PDO prevents execution of SQL code, it doesn't necessarily escape PHP tags (or does it?  This is basically my question.)

Now let's say the user visits another page that executes this query:

```
    $connection = new PDO(//some database info);
    $query = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM Rooms;");
    $query->execute();
```

And then it loops over the results, echoing them as options in a select input in an html form like this:

```
    <select>
    <option value = 1>Kitchen</option>
    <option value = 2>Bathroom</option>
    <option value = 3><?php var_dump($connection); ?></option>
    </select>
```

I've tried doing this, and the php tags in the database echo out with HTML comment tags, resulting in a blank entry in the select input, like this:

```
    <option value = 3><!--?php var_dump($connection) ?--></option>
```

Obviously, the php was not executed.  That's great, but I'm curious what decided to escape the tags.  MySQL?  PHP itself?  Can I always count on this behavior, i.e. that php code returned from a database will parse as an html comment?

Comment: The only time you open up your PHP code to injection is if you use an [`eval()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) on any user generated content. *Please note that this is a terrible idea. Never ever do it.* As far as what's doing that nice escaping for you, I've got no clue.

Comment: I suppose you'd also run into trouble if you generated your PHP page with some other kind of pre-preproccesser, but that's simply insanity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. PHP code is just plain text. Unless that text gets placed into an executable context, it will NEVER get executed. E.g. you'd need something like

```
$php_code_from_db = $db->fetchRow('php_code');
eval($php_code_from_db);
```

Dumping it out as you are in your snippets would simply send raw PHP code to the client's browser. Some of it WILL get interpreted as invalid HTML, e.g.

```
<?php
echo "Hello"
?>
World
```

would render as just `World` in a browser, since `<? ... ?>` would be seen as an invalid/unknown HTML tag.

Futhermore, PHP code is meaningless to a browser. 99.9999% of the world's web surfers are NOT going to have PHP installed on their computer. And even if they did, the browser wouldn't execute any php code it received from a website, embedded in some html.

Comment: I don't think this is exactly the question he's asking. Though it does answer part of it. The OP wants to know WHY the output is escaped as HTML. I haven't got a clue personally, but maybe you do?

Comment: Well, nothing in PDO would convert `<?` to `<!--?`. Nor would something like htmlspecialchars. That'd simply do `&lt;?`, not add html comments.

Comment: Exactly. That's why I'm baffled.

Comment: It occurred to me that php doesn't get executed by the browser, but I guess my question was more: does php outputted from a database never execute?  I guess your answer is that such outputs occur after the script has executed, unlike, for instance, php variables that come in from an include statement or something.  Is that right?

Comment: my original code example shows how "output from a database" would have to be treated to be executed. just pulling text from a db and stuffing it into a php variable would NOT execute any php code embedded in that text.